# PHP MVC in Joomla Component

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla

Im working on a pre created joomla component which using the MVC Architecture, My problem like this:

In Models i have a `.php` file with database fetch function as

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.model' );


class class_name extends JModel
{

var $_data;

    function getlast_year(){
        $query = 'SELECT year FROM `table` ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 0,1';
        $this->_db->setQuery( $query );
        return $this->_db->loadResult();
    }

}
```

I added a new function to the same class file: (I have updated the table columns too in MVC /tables)

as:

```
function getAttendenceData()
{
    $query="SELECT id,octSec,octNin,octSect,octSec,octTwent FROM `table`";
        $this->_db->setQuery( $query );
        //$this->_data = $this->_db->loadObjectList();
        $this->_data = $this->_db->loadObject();
        return $this->_db->loadObjectList();
}
```

but in **view** i cant still access the fetched data from the above new function but older functions are working property

Comment: 1. First check if you are actually getting some data from the query. do `print_r($this->_db->loadObjectList())` in above function. 2. If yes, then what's the code in the view where you're accessing this data?

Comment: Thanks `Vikk` query works fine. i access data as `$this->data as $r` then `$r->id` data fetches from older functions are fetched fine only the problem with the new function

Comment: In that case, can you post the code where you're retrieving data from model and assigning it to the view variable? This should be in the `view.html.php` file of your view.

Comment: @Vikk This Components is so complex not possible to post the code :-) .. btw can u tell me how to retrieving data from model and assigning it to the view variable ?

Comment: @vikk there is some code as `$items= & $this->get( 'Data');`

Comment: This should be `$items= & $this->get( 'AttendenceData');`, if you want to retrieve data from your `getAttendenceData()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer but response to the comment.

First in your `view.html.php` file, you'll have to retrieve data from the model.

`$attendance_data = & $this->get('AttendenceData');`

This'll give you the object list as you are returning from your getAttendenceData() function.

Now assign it to a view variable (lets say `data`).

`$this->assignRef('data', $attendance_data);`

Now you can access this data in your view:

```
foreach($data as $r)
{
    echo $r->id;
}
```

Comment: assignRef is deprecated since Joomla 1.6. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883180/joomla-3-what-to-use-instead-of-assignref

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the problem that you are attempting to fetch the data twice?

With this line you retrieve it and store it locally in the class's _data variable.

```
$this->_data = $this->_db->loadObject();
```

With this line you attempt to retrieve the data again but you've already retrieved it (if there was only one result). You therefore are probably returning a false

```
return $this->_db->loadObjectList();
```

You should *probably* return $this->_data at the end of the function - assuming the original function you are copying was indeed functional.

Comment: hi Dean thanks a lot for the answer it was not the issue .. its was as Vikk was told ! thanks !