# Joomla 3 - What to use instead of assignRef?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In my project I have this method in my view:

```
public function elegirSeleccionados(){
    $this->assignRef('pagination', $this->get('pagination'));
    $this->assignRef('items', $this->get('recientes'));
    $this->assignRef('list', $this->get('list'));
    parent::display();
}
```

`assignRef` is deprecated / removed in this Joomla 3.

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***assignRef() and assign() are not needed anymore***, since Joomla 1.6+
requires at least PHP 5.2 (PHP5 uses assign by reference).

Use in view.html.php

`$this->pagination = $this->get('pagination')`

and in the template just call `$this->pagination`.

To get your skills up to date check the official [Joomla! Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers)

Answer (score 0):

txs for this, but in my view (default.tpl) zeh val will not been shown

### **view.html.php**

```
$this->my_string = "ledl";
<br>
return parent::display($tpl);
```

### **default.tpl**

```
<bold>{$this->my_string}</bold>
```

Comment: The extension should be .php not .tpl
If you want to use .tpl, you have to set a different erxtension with
$this->setLayoutExt('tpl')